# MP3 file Live streaming with node js

Tags: node.js, audio, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming, node-streams

I'm trying upload a .mp3 file to node server so that multiple users can access that file when I play it. Similar to radio, when i start playing the song, all the users connected to that server should also be in the same position of audio.

Tried many ways using methods suggested in many Q/A, blogs, but needed a straight forward approach that handles this purpose.

Any working code/pointers or guidelines will be of great help

Comment: have you got any solution yet?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [icecast](http://icecast.org/) in order to stream your mp3 files and manage them on node using [node-icy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icy). Plus, if you want to have multiple channels listening to a single instance, I would recommend socket.io. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

Icecast (aka icecast2) will have a random delay between all listeners.  It will be a few seconds of delay between each of them.  I stream my own music.  I have computers and stereos in each room playing the same stream.  When you move from room to room, you get to hear the same chorus again.  Or miss the chorus entirely.  At transitions, 2 different songs play in my house depending on the delays.

Did you need millisecond inaccuracy in the positions for every listener?  Or is a few seconds of inaccuracy good enough?  If you need millisecond inaccuracy, icecast is not the solution you want.  It has seconds of inaccuracy between listeners.